# How to get the list of users accessing the Azure data lake store with power shell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I am trying to get a number of users are accessing my data lake with the power shell script, I tried with the below code but it's giving the ID of the users but I want their names also. Please help with that.

```
Get-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItemAclEntry -Account 'mylake' -Path '/'
```

Getting the results like below, so I want the name also with the user id, if not possible need Name and access details like user or Group and type of access they have.

Comment: Any update? Is it useful for you?

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, when we successfully run the command `Get-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItemAclEntry`, we will get a DataLakeStoreItemAce class. The class does not have a property to indicate the user or group name. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.commands.datalakestore.models.datalakestoreitemace?view=azurerm-ps.
[image]

[image]

So if you want to get the user or group name, we need to run other commands to get it. For example

```
# get user name 
Get-AzureRmADUser -ObjectId < the id you get>

#get group name
Get-AzureRmADGroup -ObjectId <the id you get>
```

[image]
[image]